# Symfony 4 "code": 401, "message": "Invalid credentials." jwt authentication error

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony4

I'm trying to make a jwt authentication with Symfony 4

I configured my project as follow

```yaml
// security.yaml 

security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
                pattern:   ^/api
                stateless: true
                guard:
                    authenticators:
                        - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

        main:
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

```yaml
// routes.yaml

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

```
// .env

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=d96058cb8b34d7061148465f3d286ae4
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
```

```yaml
//lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' # required for token creation
    public_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'  # required for token verification
    pass_phrase:      'd96058cb8b34d7061148465f3d286ae4'
    token_ttl:        3600
```

```php
//UserRepository.php

class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?User
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
```

and I generated 2 keys (private and public) in a folder named Jwt inside the config folder.

Now according to a documentation that I followed if I run:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

I'll be able to get a token like that in return

```
{
   "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MzQ3Mjc1MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoia29ybGVvbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0MzQ2NDExMzYifQ.nh0L_wuJy6ZKIQWh6OrW5hdLkviTs1_bau2GqYdDCB0Yqy_RplkFghsuqMpsFls8zKEErdX5TYCOR7muX0aQvQxGQ4mpBkvMDhJ4-pE4ct2obeMTr_s4X8nC00rBYPofrOONUOR4utbzvbd4d2xT_tj4TdR_0tsr91Y7VskCRFnoXAnNT-qQb7ci7HIBTbutb9zVStOFejrb4aLbr7Fl4byeIEYgp2Gd7gY"
}
```

but instead I got this error:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Bad Request","exception":[{"message":"Invalid JSON.","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\B [...]
```

and when I used postman 
and send

```
{
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test"
}`
url : `http://localhost:8000/api/login_check`
method : `POST`
```

I got this error
 `{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid credentials."
}`

could you please tell me why i got this error and how to fix it 
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuER6.jpg)

Comment: I've worked with React + Symfony 4 + Lewik JWT auth but the key used in the post aren't  `password & username` but `_password & _username`

Comment: In additional to this, please verify if you have an User as "test / test" in your database

Comment: i  tried but i didn't work
username and password must be provided 
the pass_phrase  in the  lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml  and  in .env should they be the same as the password that i generated  the keys with  ???

Comment: do i need to add a controller or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Your authorization endpoint is in `"/api/api_login_check"`.

And to access the `"/api/api_login_check"` route, you need to log in, because your access_control in `security.yaml` prohibits unauthorized access to the `/api` because of this line.

```
 - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Solution, change the endpoint to another route not starting with /api/....

Answer (score -1):

Add this at the end of your `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1"
```